# SQL Insert parameter in C# / .NET

Tags: c#, sql

I need to insert a string list into a table on SQL server 2014. The IDE is Visual Studio 2015, the programming language is C#.

When I run the program, the error is:

> Incorrect syntax near 'j'.

In addition, I am confused about the type of second parameter in `VALUES (ID, Name, RSSI)`. When I set `Name` as "Jason" or "Alice", it works well. However, when I use `items[0]` or `items[1]`, it fails.

```
//items refer to the scanned Bluetooth devices
List<string> items;

//use Bluetooth scan devices and record them in items;
private void scan()
{
  updateUI("Starting Scan..");
  BluetoothClient client = new BluetoothClient();
  devices = client.DiscoverDevicesInRange();
  updateUI("Scan complete");
  updateUI(devices.Length.ToString() + " devices discovered");

  foreach (BluetoothDeviceInfo d in devices)
  {
    items.Add(d.DeviceName);
  }

  updateDeviceList();
}

// ........................

// use sql to insert the items into a table on SQL server

for (int j = 0; j < items.Count; j++)
{
  cmd.CommandText = "INSERT BeaconInfo (ID, Name, RSSI) VALUES (171, items[j], 276)";
//ID is int type, Name is varchar type, RSSI is int type
  cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

  sqlConnection1.Open();
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  sqlConnection1.Close();
}
```

Comment: That is because you can't refer to .NET variables or objects from SQL. The `items[j]` part is wrong here, you need to pass in a parameter. Google for SQL Server SqlCommand parameters and see examples on how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to do this is using parameters. You cannot refer to .NET objects or anything from within the SQL so you must pass in the values to use in a different manner.

To do this using parameters, here's the SQL you should use:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT BeaconInfo (ID, Name, RSSI) VALUES (171, @item, 276)";
```

and then you should set its value:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@item", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = items[j];
```

Comment: Thank you! I need to use the SQL parameter.

Comment: I still got an error "The variable name '@item' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored " procedure" I guess it is from the for loop, the @item cannot be defined and used more than one time.

Comment: Correct, set its value only inside the loop but create and add it outside.

Answer (score 1):

`items[j]` is not a thing that the SQL Server would have any clue about how to use. Everything you are passing in that string is just sent to the SQL Server to be processed there. You need to pass a SQL Parameter to your statement:

```
for (int j = 0; j < items.Count; j++)
{
     cmd = new SqlCommand();
     cmd.CommandText = "INSERT BeaconInfo (ID, Name, RSSI) VALUES (171, @item, 276)";
     //ID is int type, Name is varchar type, RSSI is int type
     cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

     sqlConnection1.Open();
     cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@item", items[j]));
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     sqlConnection1.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you,  "New SQLParameter" has red line. It seems to add some library or modify other parts....?

Comment: I'd suggest the use of a `Try/Catch` block in addition to this solution.

Comment: I still got an error "The variable name '@item' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored " procedure" I guess it is from the for loop, the @item cannot be defined and used more than one time.

Comment: @QuickLearner Sorry, the issue there is that you are re-using the same SqlCommand object repeatedly for all of your commands instead of a new one for each iteration through the loop. I'll edit to show.

Answer (score 1):

You should use parameters to avoid SQL Injection.

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT BeaconInfo (ID, Name, RSSI) VALUES (@ID, @NAME, @RSSI)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", 171);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", items[j]);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RSSI", 276);
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
```

Also, put your opening of connection and execution inside a `Try/Catch` block.

```
try
{    
    sqlConnection1.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + e);
}
    sqlConnection1.Close();
```

Note: `ID` and `RSSI` don't have to necessarily be added as parameters if you plan to leave the same hard-coded value, but in case you plan to add/pass those values as arguments returned from another function, then you must add them as shown above.

Answer (score -2):

items[j] is part of a string here. It's not the actual variable.

This is one way to get the items[j] value placed into the string.

```
cmd.CommandText = string.Format("INSERT BeaconInfo (ID, Name, RSSI) VALUES (171, {0}, 276)", items[j]);
```

A safer way is to it:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT BeaconInfo (ID, Name, RSSI) VALUES (171, @Name, 276)";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", items[j]);
```

Comment: While this would technically work, it's very bad advice to give to someone who doesn't understand passing information from .Net to SQL. Should be using a SQLParameter instead.

Comment: Please don't teach sql injection problems as a way to solve problems here on Stack Overflow. Show the correct way using proper parameters.

Comment: Why even suggest the wrong way as another option? Especially without explaining why it's a bad idea.

Comment: Let's see. Visit stackover.com, try to start being helpful and then these vets jump down your throat. I'm not sure I should be here taking time to help anyone. Thanks for the welcome.

Comment: The first part of your answer doesn't just have sql injection issue, it will not work.  Since `item` is a `List<string>` then you need quotes around the value in the SQL for it to be valid.  Determining when you do or do not need quotes is actually another good reason to always use parameters instead.